# Count the total number of words from stdin

Tags: python, stdin

I have to read a text file name (the text file is already on my computer), open it, read it, and print the total number of words.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
import sys

file = sys.stdin
    
with open(file) as f: # also tried using open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    data = f.readlines()
    words = data.split()
    
    no_of_words = 0
    for word in words:
        no_of_words += 1
        print(no_of_words)
```

But when I try to run it, it shows the following error:

```py
"with open(file) as f:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper"
```

Comment: It won't even recognise the "data.split"

Comment: you can already treat `sys.stdin` as a file-like! `echo "test1 test2" | python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read().split())'` as it's an instance of `io.TextIOWrapper` as it reports https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-count-words-in-text-file/  there's also countless other examples from various sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file name using `input()`, test if the file exists, read the file contents, split it into words, and then just count them.

Something like this is a good starting point:

```py
from pathlib import Path

text_file = Path(input('Type the file name: '))

if text_file.exists() and text_file.is_file():
    words = len(text_file.read_text().split())
    print(f'{text_file} has {words} words')
else:
    print(f'File not found: {text_file}')
```